# PHP Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity,

Tags: php

I'm trying to get links from a website using a bunch of php codes but it seem to return this error for certain programs.
"PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity "

I've tried various methods online but none seem to work.

```
function follow_links($url) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $linklist = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a");
    foreach ($linklist as $link) {
        $l = $link->getAttribute("href");
        if (substr($l, 0, 1) == "/" && substr($l, 0, 2) != "//") {
            $l = parse_url($url) ["scheme"] . "://" . parse_url($url) ["host"] . $l;
        } else if (substr($l, 0, 2) == "//") {
            $l = parse_url($url) ["scheme"] . ":" . $l;
        } else if (substr($l, 0, 2) == "./") {
            $l = parse_url($url) ["scheme"] . "://" . parse_url($url) ["host"] . dirname(parse_url($url) ["path"]) . substr($l, 1);
        } else if (substr($l, 0, 1) == "#") {
            $l = parse_url($url) ["scheme"] . "://" . parse_url($url) ["host"] . parse_url($url) ["path"] . $l;
        } else if (substr($l, 0, 3) == "../") {
            $l = parse_url($url) ["scheme"] . "://" . parse_url($url) ["host"] . "/" . $l;
        } else if (substr($l, 0, 11) == "javascript:") {
            continue;
        } else if (substr($l, 0, 5) != "https" && substr($l, 0, 4) != "http") {
            $l = parse_url($url) ["scheme"] . "://" . parse_url($url) ["host"] . "/" . $l;
        }
        echo $l . "\n";
    }
}
```

The actual result is supposed to print the URL's available.

Comment: the website i'm trying to crawl is https://devfolio.co/hackathons

Comment: Always worth trying to see what HTML you are getting back `$page = file_get_contents($url); echo $page;`.